# AJAX returns empty value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get my AJAX request to PHP working. It should, after sending the AJAX request loop through some items and then send back an array of data. The problem is that it returns an empty string.

Here's the code:

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {

    $available = array();

    for($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++) {

        $gt = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),3);

        $check_url = "SOMEURL" . $gt . ".card";
        $check_url_source = file_get_contents( $check_url );

        $exists = ( preg_match( "#<div id=\"Gamerscore\">--</div>#i", $check_url_source ) ) ? false : true;

        if($exists == false) {
            array_push($available, $gt);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($available, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/GamertagChecker/helpers/magic.php',
        data: {action: 'load'},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            console.log(output);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception){
            console.log("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Comments  [archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132626/discussion-on-question-by-chris-ajax-returns-empty-value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through a lot of solutions and research by others here I've finally found the problem.

Because I was using the PHPStorm IDE, I was also using the build-in server. Unfortunately there is a bug in the server which causes `$_POST` to not work.

After copying the files to a different IDE I finally got it working. Thanks to everyone who tried to help, your effort is much appreciated!